# Jenkinsfile maven custom settings.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkinsfile with several maven steps, how can I specify a custom maven settings to use in the entire pipeline avoiding to use withMaven() in eac step.

My ideal solution would be something that could be setted in "tools" pipeline section, but can't find it:

```
tools {
    maven 'maven3'
    jdk 'openjdk-1.8'
}
```

Comment: `entire pipeline avoiding to use withMaven() in eac step.`  How many times do you need `withMaven(..)` ?

Comment: 4 times, I am using configFileProvider instead of withMaven() with the fileId parameterized, works fine and with this you only have to set the "fieldId" parameter once,... but it keeps 4 duplicate code blocks.

Comment: Why do you use withMaven 4 times? Can you show those things ?

Answer (score 0):

withMaven(..) DSL is meant to be within stage scope that's the reason I don't think it can be reusable in other stages.

But you can do it in a different way i.e.

1. If your Jenkins master and agent has docker runtime you can achieve your target easily :

declarative Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       docker {
         image 'maven:3-alpine'
         args  '-v /tmp:/tmp'
       }  
    }
    
    stages {
        stage("version bump") {
            steps {
                sh "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT"
            }
        }
        stage("build") {
            steps {
                sh "mvn clean install"
            }
        }
        stage("deploy") {
            steps {
                sh "mvn deploy"
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

scripted Jenkinsfile

```
node {

    docker.image('maven:3-alpine').inside {
        stage('version bump') {
            sh 'mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
        }
        stage('build') {
            sh 'mvn clean install'
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            sh 'mvn deploy'
        }
    }
}
```

2. if your Jenkins master or agent has apache maven installed , `mvn` command will be available in any of the commandline `sh` or `bat`

example on scripted pipeline

```
node {
  def mvn="mvn --batch-mode -s path/to/settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=${WORKSPACE}/.m2"

  stage('version bump') {
     sh "${mvn} versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.3-SNAPSHOT"
  }
  stage('build') {
     sh "${mvn} clean install"
  }
  stage('deploy') {
     sh "${mvn} deploy"
  }
}
```